# YouTube API V3 - How to get ALL game live streams

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get "ALL" game live streams from youtube using API.

The way I first used is through "Search.list" with parameters: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&eventType=live&maxResults=50&type=video&videoCategoryId=20. But in this way when I try to iterate results using PageToken, I can only get around 100 results while in the API response I can see "totalResults" is around 2000. Then I came into this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918405/youtube-api-v3-page-tokens/25928207#25928207) and realized that "Search.list" is actually kind of "ranking" algorithm instead of "fetch all data from DB", which means "totalResults" is just an estimated number of results.

Then I came to use "liveBroadcasts.list" but it returns no results: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.liveBroadcasts.list?part=id&broadcastStatus=active&maxResults=50&_h=8&

And for other APIs, they either need channelId or other ids.

Is there any way to get all game live streams regardless of any ids?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Youtube Category ID list](https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c), Gaming resides on number 20 category. In case you want to try a different category in the future, instead of videoCategoryId=20, you can try videoCategoryId=31 - that's for Anime/Animation.

Try to run this on your browser to get all live streams:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&videoCategoryId=20&regionCode=US&maxResults=50&key=SERVER_API_KEY_HERE
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is just the way that I first tried in my question, the problem is I can only get partial results instead of all results - after iterating 2 to 3 pages there are no results any more, although the response from the api said there will be 2000 results.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: yes but this api cost too much ... 1 query costs 100 in quota ...