# Search provides nextPageToken but items are empty

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube Data API version 3 and it seems there is an internal threshold (200) to limit the number of results. While the nextPageToken is available, the api returns an empty list. I am trying to get a list of videos from an specific channel ('UCJEy8aBnqDymMIcJCh72gMw'), it contains more than 3K videos and you can only get the first 200 and after that you will getting next tokens but the items are empty.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?pageToken=XXXXX&order=date&part=snippet&key=XXXXXXXX&channelId=UCJEy8aBnqDymMIcJCh72gMw

Comment: @ramtin-m-seraj Maybe Some Videos Restrict in your area you can try to check with other region or country

Comment: @ramtin-m-seraj Use This tag in your link `&regionCode=US`

Comment: @Alish I tried that as well and also `publishAfter` and `publishBefore`, but non of them worked. thanks

Comment: I have same problem, not always 200 limit, for some keywords it reached 300+, sometimes 400+, and never over 500.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Fasoeu Not really, seems YouTube do it intentionally.

Comment: @RamtinM.Seraj thank you. After further investigation I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918405/youtube-api-v3-page-tokens. See the accepted answer.
It seems it depends on the YouTube' search engine itself and its probabilistic calculations

Comment: @Fasoeu Thanks, that was interesting.