# youtube api nextPageToken still returns results

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a similar issue to [YouTube API returns nextPageToken with empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179662/youtube-api-returns-nextpagetoken-with-empty-lists)

I'm trying to understand why the 'nextPageToken' appears when there are no results in the items list. Below is the developer site to test.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCfMmZSKgLjfpDkXzpffZGBw&maxResults=10&order=date&pageToken=CCgQAA&q=Arlo+Pro&_h=4&

If we use the the 'prevPageToken' it returns 8 of the 10 results so would expect that the 'nextPageToken' would no longer appear? Is there a way to resolve?

There is a google issue that is similar too: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62699251