# Empty response pages on YouTube API v3 request

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get all videos from a channel using the youtube api. I'm using python to open request and get the json response from the server. The channel I'm testing on has 1500 videos, but I'm only able to get around 500 videos, because the last 10 or so `nextPageToken` responses are empty.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=" + channelid + "&order=date&key=" + mykey
```

This is my initial call where I get the first `nextPageToken` and the first 50 videos.

```
while "nextPageToken" in json_data:
    nextPageToken = json_data["nextPageToken"]
    tokenDictionary.append(nextPageToken)
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&&type=video&channelId=" + channelid + "&order=date&key=" + mykey + "&pageToken=" + nextPageToken)
    json_data = r.json()
    nextPageToken = json_data["nextPageToken"]
    print("token not encountered")
    tokenDictionary.append(nextPageToken)
    print(json_data["nextPageToken"])
```

Afterwards, I do the same thing with newly encountered tokens. I don't exceed out of my quota. The channel only had 6 livestream videos.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be due to an issue with the Youtube API itself. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179662/youtube-api-returns-nextpagetoken-with-empty-lists) delves into it. There are lots of open issues on google's issue tracker with this same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube search has a soft limit of 500 videos returned. Recommend breaking up search by dates so each query returns < 500, then combine results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested my code on a channel with around 200 videos as well, but it only returned 100 videos though. I will give chunk methods a go still.