# Search results have a couple of more "nextPageToken", but no more items

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I call YT.Search API and then iterate over the results. Page by Page.
At some point, there are still more pages to iterate, but the "items" array is empty.

I had to add a condition to break the iteration loop.

```
if (searchResults.items.length == 0 || !('nextPageToken' in searchResults)) {
```

Is that a known issue?[image]

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25928207/311130) but I recall it wasn't like that a few weeks ago.

I used to call the YT search and get ~2000 results per keyword.

Comment: Indeed this is a known issue of the API. I came across it myself too. In any case, you may well [file an inquiry](http://issuetracker.google.com/) to be answered (officially) by Google staff. Also note that `Search.list` does not return more than 500 items when using its request parameter [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) and, at the same time, do set its request parameter  [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) to `video`.

Comment: Has this changed recently? I don't think it returned up to ~500 results a month ago.

Comment: According to [official documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317030114/https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) it seems to be limited to 500 since 17/03/2016.